# how to format the display of results after a sql query

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have been trying to format my results which is being sorted by the first letter of the surname but having problems

i need it to echo in the following format

```
<section>                       
                      <div id="slider">
                        <div class="slider-content">
                          <ul>
                            <li id="LETTER"><a name="LETTER" class="title">LETTER</a><ul>
                                <li><a href="#">SURNAME</a></li>
                              </ul>
                            </li>

                              </ul>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>         
                    </section>
```

i am have tried to split it so (see code bellow) but it not rendering correctly

```
<html>
<head>
<title>MySQLi Read Records</title>
</head>
<body><section>                       
                      <div id="slider">
                        <div class="slider-content">
                          <ul>
<?php
//include database connection
include 'db_connect.php';

//query all records from the database
$query = "  SELECT name,
         surname,
         mobile,
         UPPER (LEFT(surname, 1)) AS letter
    FROM contacts 
ORDER BY surname";

//execute the query
$result = $mysqli->query( $query );

//get number of rows returned
$num_results = $result->num_rows;

//this will link us to our add.php to create new record


if( $num_results > 0){ //it means there's already a database record


    //creating our table heading


    //loop to show each records
    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
            //extract row
            //this will make $row['firstname'] to
            //just $firstname only
            extract($row);

            //creating new table row per record
            if (!isset($lastLetter) || $lastLetter != $row['letter'])
{
 echo '<li id="', $row['letter'], '"><a name="', $row['letter'],'" class="title">', $row['letter'],'</a><ul>';
    $lastLetter = $row['letter'];
  echo "bottom";  
}
echo "<li><a href='#'>{$surname} - {$name}</a></li>";


    }


}else{
    //if database table is empty
    echo "No records found.";
}

//disconnect from database
$result->free();
$mysqli->close();

?> </ul>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>         
                    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

i need to find where and how to echo these sections so it would be like this

:- UPDATE -:

with the reply i got itested it and it goes something like this

```
<body>
<section>
<div id="slider">
<div class="slider-content">
<ul>
<li id="E"><a name="E" class="title">E</a>
  <ul>
  bottom
  <li><a href='#'>egg - smash</a></li>
  <li id="S"><a name="S" class="title">S</a>
    <ul>
    bottom
    <li><a href='#'>surname</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>surname</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>surname</a></li>
    <li id="Z">
    <a name="Z" class="title">Z</a>
    <ul>
      bottom
      <li><a href='#'>zoo</a></li>
      <!-- </ul> BAD UL ?-->
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

when it should be

```
<section>                       
                      <div id="slider">
                        <div class="slider-content">
                          <ul>
                            <li id="s"><a name="s" class="title">s</a><ul>
                                <li><a href="#">surname</a></li>
                              </ul>
                            </li>

                              </ul>
                            </li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>         
                    </section>
```

Comment: Your original HTML looks a little confusing, it's hard to tell what element needs to go where. It's possible the tags are not matching up the way you intended. Can you check it and maybe post some sample/desired output?

Comment: why it should display S, im seeing its doing the right thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALWAYS indent your code, AlWAYS run tests on variables, do not take steps skipping simple testing before like looping

```
<body>
    <section>                       
        <div id="slider">
            <div class="slider-content">
                <ul>
                <?php
                    //include database connection
                    include 'db_connect.php';
                    //query all records from the database
                    $query = "  SELECT name,
                    surname,
                    mobile,
                    UPPER (LEFT(surname, 1)) AS letter
                    FROM contacts 
                    ORDER BY letter ASC";
                    //execute the query
                    $result = $mysqli->query( $query );


        //TEST 1st print_r($result); if not working there is an error on your sql


                    //get number of rows returned
                    $num_results = $result->num_rows;
                    //this will link us to our add.php to create new record
                    if( $num_results > 0){ //it means there's already a database records
                    //creating our table heading
                    //loop to show each records
                    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
                    //extract row
                    //this will make $row['firstname'] to
                    //just $firstname only
                    extract($row);

                    //creating new table row per record
                    if (!isset($lastLetter) || $lastLetter != $row['letter'])
                    {
                    echo '<li id="', $row['letter'], '"><a name="', $row['letter'],'" class="title">', $row['letter'],'</a><ul>';
                    $lastLetter = $row['letter'];
                    echo "bottom";  
                    }
                    echo "<li><a href='#'>{$surname} - {$name}</a></li>";
                    }
                    }else{
                    //if database table is empty
                    echo "No records found.";
                    }
                    //disconnect from database
                    $result->free();
                    $mysqli->close();
                ?> 
        <!-- </ul> BAD UL ?--> 
                </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>         
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply. i have tried your replay and still renders wrong ill update my question to reflect on the rendering

Comment: with out proving this works `print_r($result);` you are wasting your time on the loop when your problem is the variable and if the problem is the variable then your problem is the source of it, which is you sql

Comment: try this in your gui db management system `"SELECT name,
                    surname,
                    mobile,
                    UPPER (LEFT(surname, 1)) AS letter
                    FROM contacts 
                    ORDER BY letter ASC"` then come and try it on the php